# Umbraco - Getting Data from U7 Grid

Tags: razor, umbraco

I want to create a component which allows editors quickly enter (edit) multiple links. I’m using U7 Grid which is ok for that task. The problem I got is with having data back. Normally I would use 'CurrentPage.footerLinks' which returns Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray and it is easy to process. 
This time, however, I can’t use ‘CurrentPage’. I need to access my data like that

```
Node node = new Node(3167);
var links = node.GetProperty("footerLinks");
```

Which returns ( type of umbraco.NodeFactory.Property) :

```
[ { "linkUrl": "#", "linkText": "News" }, { "linkUrl": "#", "linkText": "General Information" }, { "linkUrl": "#", "linkText": "How to Book"}]
```

How will I access that data so I can loop through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
Node node = new Node(3167);
dynamic links = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(node.GetProperty<string>("footerLinks"));

@foreach (var link in links) {
<p>@link.linkText</p>
}
```